# How to draw phylogenetic tree?

Tags: mactex, trees, qtree, pst-tree

I'm using Mac OSX Mavericks and have downloaded LaTex. I am currently learning how to draw phylogenetic tree. Can someone teach me?

I have copied a sample of code for the phylogenetic tree. it uses the newicktree package. But my compiler outputs 
 file"...sty" not found.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  That said, make sure you've either installed the package correctly or that the package (the `sty` file) is in the same directory as your `tex` file.

Comment: Thanks @SeanAllred. I have installed the basic-mactex only. Can you tell me what packages do I still have to install? plus, I never have minded whether my tex file are in the same directory.

Comment: It looks like it's only available here: http://cbr.jic.ac.uk/dicks/software/newicktree/.  Download the `sty` file to the same directory as your `tex` file :)  If it still doesn't work after that, open Terminal and run `sudo tlmgr install pst-node pst-tree`—a quick look at the `sty` file reveals that these are dependencies and I'm not sure which packages come in the 'Basic' MacTeX distribution.  (It's *always* simpler to install the full distribution… trust me.)

Comment: Great, i think I'm progressing. current problem : file "pst-tree.sty" not found.

Comment: See the comment above.

Comment: I have done the tasks in terminals. so I tried clicking the typeset. The problem that shows is file "pstricks.sty" not found. help @SeanAllred

Comment: Leave it to install overnight. Things will be *much* simpler with the full installation. Otherwise, you are likely to keep discovering more and more things you need which is likely to get extremely annoying. (Especially if your connection is slow and you need to meet a deadline.) However, this may depend on what most easily annoys you so ymmv ;).

Comment: i think i'll be downloading the full installation. You have just persuaded me. but after I draw this phylogenetic tree. Coz reinstalling mactex, I think it will be again another problem of mine.

Comment: In that case, you are going to end up installing a bunch of things to typeset the tree and then starting over. However, if you are in a rush for the tree, maybe you have to. So just keep following the errors. `pstricks.sty` not found means you need to install `pstricks`...